# codeigniter active record batch update where where clause equals array index

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, batch-processing

I have an array of post data ($data) in codeigniter that looks like the attached image.

[image]

And a database that looks like:

id: 3
val: 37.10119357072203

-

id: 4
val: -122.06634521484374

I want to insert the array value into the 'val' field based on the array key matching the database 'id' field. How do I do this using codeigniter's update_batch. My model is currently:

```
public function edit_config($data){
        $this->db->update_batch('extra_config', $data,'val');
    }
```

but I get the error:

```
One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index.
```

---

[image]

Comment: Can you dump this $data to see what you are sending to CI

Comment: can you echo the query using `$this->db->last_query()` and post it here?

Comment: @Svetlio - `Array ( [val] => Array ( [3] => 37.10119357072203 [4] => -122.06634521484374 [5] => 37.51571709945411 `... is print_r($data)

Comment: @newCodex - I'm not sure where to do this echo - I tried placing it after the call to the edit_config function in my controller and I just get a blank page

Comment: @mheavers just below `$this->db->update_batch('extra_config', $data,'val');`

Comment: @mheavers go to Codeigniter documentation and see how your array must be structured for update_batch as it is not the right way at the moment ;)

Comment: @newCodex - that doesn't work because of the error that occurs in update_batch (see revised post)

Comment: @Svetlio - I've seen the documentation - I guess I'm trying to find out how to get it into the format without manually constructing an array of over 100 database rows and their respective ids / values. That's why the question is regarding how to use update_batch given that I only have array keys and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prepare your data its not normal not to touch it from the incoming request..

```
public function edit_config($data){
     $updateData = array();
     foreach($data['val'] as $key=>$value) {
         $updateData[] = array('id'=>$key, 'val'=>$value);
     }

     $this->db->update_batch('extra_config', $updateData,'id');
}
```